# How to make a loop run a specific number of times

Tags: python, pygame

I'm writing a program that is supposed to draw a random number of squares on the screen, at random positions, with a random colour. I tried to get this to happen, but it wasn't working (instead just drawing one square and putting it at a new position every frame).

I decided to abandon the random amount of squares idea, and just make it draw three. But it still did the exact same thing. According to the websites I've read, you should be able to use a For loop to draw them a certain number of times. However, the websites weren't very clear and used some terminology I haven't heard before. I thought it would be easier to do something like this, but I'm relatively new to programming so I might be doing something wrong.

```
population = 0

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    pcol = (random.choice(colour_list))
    px = random.randint(50, 750)
    py = random.randint(50, 750)

    screen.fill(GREY)

    for population in range(0, 3):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, pcol, (px, py, 50, 50))
        population += 1

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Try it without the line `population += 1`; the variable automatically increments each time you run through the loop.

Comment: Your `pygame.draw.rect()` loop reuses the same x,y coordinates for all three squares.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've to generate different random positions (`px`, `py`) and colors (`pcol`) in the `for`-loop, so every rectangle gets its own random position and color:

```py
screen.fill(GREY)

for _ in range(0, 3):
    pcol = (random.choice(colour_list))
    px = random.randint(50, 750)
    py = random.randint(50, 750)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, pcol, (px, py, 50, 50))

pygame.display.update()
```

---

If you want to stay the random rectangles persistent, then you've to generate a list of data before the main loop:

```py
population = []
for _ in range(0, 3):
    pcol = (random.choice(colour_list))
    px = random.randint(50, 750)
    py = random.randint(50, 750)
    population.append((px, py, pcol))

while running:

    # [...]

    screen.fill(GREY)
    for px, py, pcol in population:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, pcol, (px, py, 50, 50))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

This (https://stackoverflow.com/a/57209221/11714229) answer is correct.  In addition, you can draw a random number of squares by making your for loop like this:

```
for population in range(0, randint([Min number of squares], [Max number of squares]):
```

// example:

```
for population in range(0, randint(1,15):
     //code here
```

output would be somewhere between 1 and 15 squares.

---